# Cypher to lookup and order by multiple values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a JSON document with history based entity counts and relationship counts. I want to use this lookup data for entity and relationships in Neo4j. Lookup data has around 3000 rows. For the entity counts I want to display the counts for two entities based on UUID. For relationships, I want to order by two relationship counts (related entities and related mutual entities).

For entities, I have started with the following:

```
// get JSON doc
with value.aggregations.ent.terms.buckets as data

unwind data as lookup1
unwind data as lookup2

MATCH (e1:Entity)-[r1:RELATED_TO]-(e2)
WHERE e1.uuid = '$entityId'
AND e1.uuid = lookup1.key
AND e2.uuid = lookup2.key
RETURN e1.uuid, lookup1.doc_count, r1.uuid, e2.uuid, lookup2.doc_count
ORDER BY lookup2.doc_count DESC  // just to demonstrate
LIMIT 50
```

I'm noticing that query is taking about 10 seconds. What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Attaching explain plan:

[image]

Comment: The first occurrence of e2count is in the ORDER BY so I'm guessing there's a cut/paste error. Regardless, the first things that come to mind are to run an EXPLAIN on your Cypher and see what's happening in the query plan. Also, if Entity.uuid is unique then adding a unique constraint will have the side effect of creating an index on the uuid's as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is *very* inefficient. You stated that `data` has 3,000 rows (let's call that number `D`).

1. So, your first `UNWIND` creates an intermediate result of `D` rows.
2. Your second `UNWIND` creates an intermediate result of `D**2` (i.e., 9 million) rows.
3. If your `MATCH (e1:Entity)-[r1:RELATED_TO]-(e2)` clause finds N results, that generates an intermediate result of up to N*(D**2) rows.
4. Since your `MATCH` clause specifies a non-directional relationship pattern, it finds the same pair of nodes *twice* (in reverse order). So, `N` is actually twice as large as it needs to be.

Here is an improved version of your query, which should be much faster (with N/2 intermediate rows):

```
WITH apoc.map.groupBy(value.aggregations.ent.terms.buckets, 'key') as lookup
MATCH (e1:Entity)-[r1:RELATED_TO]->(e2)
WHERE e1.uuid = $entityId AND lookup[e1.uuid] IS NOT NULL AND lookup[e2.uuid] IS NOT NULL
RETURN e1.uuid, lookup[e1.uuid].doc_count AS count1, r1.uuid, e2.uuid, lookup[e2.uuid].doc_count AS count2
ORDER BY count2 DESC
LIMIT 50
```

The trick here is that the query uses [apoc.map.groupBy](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/data-structures/map-functions/) to convert your `buckets` (a list of maps) into a single unified `lookup` map that uses the bucket `key` values as its property names. This allows the rest of the query to literally "look up" each `uuid`'s data in the unified map.

Comment: Thank you cybersam. I was ideally looking for lookup functionality over using unwind but I couldn't find examples in the apoc documentation. The reason I had non directional was that I also wanted to return entities that were also related to e1 (as opposed to from e1).  Thanks again for the support.